# How to sort an array of arrays based on the 2nd value of children arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

Perhaps we have an array of arrays such as this:

```
["a", "11.36"]
["b", "12.13"]
["c", "11.00"]
```

Is there a simple function to be able to sort them based on the 2nd index?

Comment: I know how to solve it... I just wanted an absurdly easy question that people can reference because it took me too long to research.

Comment: Fair enough. I just wanted to post something I struggled to find with some verbiage I wasn't using. I'll delete it in the morning if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

With use of [Array.prototype.sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) and [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) it would look like this

```js
const a = [
  ["a", "11.36"],
  ["b", "12.13"],
  ["c", "11.00"]
];

a.sort(([,a], [,b]) => a - b)
console.log(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```js
let arr = [["a", "11.36"], ["b", "12.13"], ["c", "11.00"]]
arr = arr.sort(function(a,b) {
    return a[1] - b[1];
});
    
console.log(arr)
```